# Conditional request as first request in sequence

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to send a request in rxjs which is conditional if the user has uploaded the file. After this, if the file is there I attach it to the user object in which I send, I then need to patch the user after posting to the files endpoint.

The issue I'm having is, as it is in a if condition on the first request I know I cannot subscribe to it. I could get around it by doing `if { } else { }` which I am trying to avoid.

Here is what it looks like.

```js
if (fileSelected) {
    this.dataService.type('files').post(fileSelected).subscribe((response) => {
        this.user.file = response;

        // I need to then post the updated user to the patch endpoint.
    });
}

this.dataService.type('users').patch(this.user).subscribe(() => {

});
```

Obviously in the example above (how I'm doing it currently) it's not waiting for the first request to finish. I know I could probably use `.pipe` and pipe something onto the end but as I said earlier, as this is the first request I am not entirely sure how this would be done.

Answer (score 5):

You want to start an observable stream with the value of `fileSelected` and then conditionally switch to other streams.

```js
const user$ = of(fileSelected).pipe(
   switchMap(selected => selected
         ? this.dataService.type('files').post(fileSelected)
         : of(undefined)
   ),
   switchMap(response => {
       this.user.file = response; // will be undefined if not selected
       return this.dataService.type('users').patch(this.user);
   })
);

user$.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

You could also make it more relevant to a user object so you are not referencing a `this.user` property from inside functional programming. This is closer to making it a RxJS operator that can be reused.

```js
function sendFiles(user, fileSelected): Observable<any> {
   return of(user).pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
         const send$ = fileSelected ? this.dataService.type('files').post(fileSelected) : of(undefined);
         return send$.pipe(map(response => (user.file = response, user)));
      ),
      switchMap(user => this.dataService.type('users').patch(user))
   );
}

sendFiles(this.user, fileSelected).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

Or maybe more simple:

```js
function sendFiles(user: User, fileSelected: boolean, {type}: DataService): Observable<any> {
   const send$ = fileSelected ? type('files').post(fileSelected) : of(undefined);
   return send$.pipe(
      map(file => ({...user, file})),
      switchMap(user => type('users').patch(user))
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mergeMap for this

```
this.dataService.type('files').post(fileSelected).pipe(
  mergeMap(response => {
    this.user.file = response;
    return this.dataService.type('users').patch(this.user)
  })
).subscribe(x => console.log("all done"));
```

Comment: The only thing with this is, I only want to do the initial files request if there is a file selected